# Run multiple functions using turtle.screen.onkey() in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

For the code:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, bgcolor

# --- functions ---

def delSec(string):
    if len(string) == 1:
        return "0" + string
    else:
        return string

def tick():
    global milisecs, ticking


    turtle.clear()

    if milisecs < 0:
        turtle.write("TIMER DONE", align='center', font=FONT)
        ticking = False
        return
    else:
        turtle.write(delSec(str(milisecs//(60*60*10)))+":"+delSec(str((milisecs%(60*60*10))//(60*10)))+":"+delSec(str((milisecs%(60*10))//10))+":"+str(milisecs%10), align='center', font=FONT)
##        turtle.write(delSec(str(milisecs//(60*60)))+":"+delSec(str((milisecs%(60*60))//(60)))+":"+delSec(str((milisecs%(60))//1)), align='center', font=FONT)
        if not paused:
              milisecs -= 1

    screen.ontimer(tick, 100)

def reset():
    global milisecs, ticking, key_reset, key_pause, key_both
    #global paused

    print("reset")

    screen.onkey(None, key_reset)  # Disable event handler inside handler
    screen.onkey(None, key_pause)  # Disable event handler inside handler
    screen.onkey(None, key_both)

    milisecs = sum(time*10)

    if not ticking:
        ticking = True
        tick()

    #paused = False

    screen.onkey(reset, key_reset)  # Reenable event handler
    screen.onkey(pause, key_pause)  # Reenable event handler
    screen.onkey(reset, key_both)
    screen.onkey(pause, key_both)

def pause():
    global paused

    print("pause/unpause")

    paused = not paused

# --- main ---

bgcolor('dodgerblue')
FONT = ("Arial", 60, "normal")

strings = input("Please enter the time: ").strip().split(' ')

time = [60 ** (len(strings) - index - 1) * int(unit) for index, unit in enumerate(strings)]

milisecs = -1
ticking = False
paused = False
key_reset = "r"
key_pause = "p"
key_both = "b"

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.color('white')

reset()

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

I want to both pause *and* reset the timer when I click the key "b". I tried doing this by running both functions reset and pause. However, as expected, it overwrites the first command of running the first function and only runs the second function when I click `b` (in this case, the function pause) I also tried the line `screen.onkey(pause, reset, key_both)`, but that created an error.

Could someone help me figure out how to run multiple functions? I can't find any parameter of .onkey() where it doesn't disable previous key-based functions. Please help!

Comment: Is there any function of the turtle module such that I can run multiple functions when I click b with just one line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frustratingly, what you're asking for is built-in to the mouse event functions:

```
onclick(fun, btn=1, add=None)
```

where the `add` argument is used to indicate whether `fun` overrides the current setting or simply adds another function to execute in this circumstance.  However, this wasn't included on the various `onkey*()` event handlers.

Below is what I consider a generic way to go about this:

```
from turtle import Screen

KEY_RESET = 'r'
KEY_PAUSE = 'p'
KEY_BOTH = 'b'

def reset():
    screen.onkey(None, KEY_RESET)  # Disable event handlers inside handler
    screen.onkey(None, KEY_BOTH)

    print("reset")

    screen.onkey(reset, KEY_RESET)  # Reenable event handlers
    screen.onkey(both, KEY_BOTH)

def pause():
    screen.onkey(None, KEY_PAUSE)  # Disable event handlers inside handler
    screen.onkey(None, KEY_BOTH)

    print("pause")

    screen.onkey(pause, KEY_PAUSE)  # Reenable event handlers
    screen.onkey(both, KEY_BOTH)

def both():
    reset()
    pause()

screen = Screen()

reset()

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

> such that I can run multiple functions when I click b with just one
>   line of code?

Yes, there's a hack we can do with `lambda` and a `tuple` but we shouldn't be thinking this way.  "Just one line of code" should not be your goal at this point.

Comment: No, sorry if I was unclear, but you solved my problem. I didn't think at all calling both functions in another function instead of calling them separately. Thank you, this definitely helped. (also, I knew that onscreenclick and onclick had those build-in, but I was wondering if it was actually true that Python's onkey functions didn't have those basic parameters)